# Spring Controller throws NullPointerException when Pass Integer Data With Ajax/Post

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass set of data in html form;

```
<form class="form-inline" id="createjobform" method="POST" th:action="@{/createJob}">
...
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nopth"
    placeholder="Number Of People To Hire" name="nopth" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control"
    id="listid" placeholder="ID" name="listid"
    title="ID of the list which associated" 
    th:value="${findOneList.id}"/>
</div>
```

listid in here, coming from another table (manytoone-onetomany) and I want to add new record with this listid. When I do it on phpmyadmin, it's working. But I want to do it with ajax post request or not without ajax, no matter actually. I tried both ways but it shows same error.

Here is my controller;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createJob", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void createJob(@RequestBody Jobs jobs,
        @RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title,
        @RequestParam(value = "description", required = false) String description,
        @RequestParam(value = "nopth", required = false) Integer nopth,
        @RequestParam(value = "lastDate", required = false) Date lastDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "listid", required = false) Long listid,
        HttpServletResponse hsr) throws IOException {

    // if I do String nopth above and then
    //jobs.setNopth(Integer.valueOf(nopth));
    // error is NumberFormatException (cannot cast string to int)

    jobs.setLastDate(lastDate);
    jobs.setTitle(title);
    jobs.setDescription(description);
    jobs.setNopth(nopth);
    Lists listttt = listsService.findOne(listid);
    jobs.setLists(listttt);

    jobsService.save(jobs);
    mavHomepage.addObject("findOneList", listsService.findOne(jobs.getId()));
    mavHomepage.addObject("mod", "VIEW_ONELIST");
    hsr.sendRedirect("/oneList?id=" + listid);
}
```

so error is;

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
exception: "java.lang.NullPointerException"
message: "No message available"
path: "/createJob"
status: 500
```

at line jobs.setNopth(nopth);

also error is;

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
exception: "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException"
message: "The given id must not be null!; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!"
path: "/createJob"
status: 500
```

at line Lists listttt = listsService.findOne(listid);

This is not with ajax/post. When I do;

```
public @ResponseBody void createJob(@RequestBody Jobs jobs,
    @RequestParam(value="listid, required="false") listid,
    HttpServletResponse hsr){

        Lists listttt = listsService.findOne(listid);
        jobs.setLists(listttt);
         ...
}
```

and ajax;

```
var formData = {
    title : $("#title").val(),
    description : $("#description").val(),
    nopth : $("#nopth").val(),
    lastDate : $("#lastDate").val(),
    listid : $("#listid").val(),
}
...
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "/createJob",
        data : JSON.stringify(formData),
....
```

same error (The given id must not be null!)

**SO HOW MUST I PASS DATA FROM FORM WHICH IS INTEGER/LONG VALUES ? WITH AJAX WOULD BE BETTER. AND THAT listid is FOREIGN KEY.**

Model Classes;

```
@Entity(name = "jobs")
public class Jobs {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "Title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "Description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "Number_Of_People_To_Hire")
private Integer nopth;

@Column(name = "Last_Application_Date")
private Date lastDate;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="listid")
private Lists lists;
```

...

```
@Entity(name = "lists")
public class Lists implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long id;

@Column(name = "List_Name")
public String listname;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lists", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Jobs> jobs;
```

I've tried to change type of nopth to String, Integer etc. and input type="text or number" no changes.

Answer (score 0):

- `@RequestBody` This annotation indicates a method parameter should be bound to the body of the web request
- So you have to fix your controller like this:

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/createJob", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void createJob(
      @RequestBody Jobs jobs,
      @RequestParam("listid") Long listid
      HttpServletResponse hsr) throws IOException {

     Lists listttt = listsService.findOne(listid);
     jobs.setLists(listttt);

     jobsService.save(jobs);

     ...

  }
  ```
- Your jquery request:

  ```
  var formData = {
      title : $("#title").val(),
      description : $("#description").val(),
      nopth : $("#nopth").val(),
      lastDate : $("#lastDate").val()
  }

  var listid : $("#listid").val(),

  var settings = {
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/createJob?listid="+listid,
    "method": "POST",
    "data": JSON.stringify(formData)
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
   }

   $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
   });
  ```

Comment: `mavHomepage.addObject("findOneList", listsService.findOne(jobs.getId()));` at this line your are getting the error because your current **jobs object has no intial value for the id** , so when you save the **jobs object** try this : `Jobs newJobs = jobsService.save(jobs);` at this point your **newJobs object** has an **id**  , so you do : `mavHomepage.addObject("findOneList", listsService.findOne(newJobs.getId()));`